# Magento 2.4.3 - Reload totals cart after ajax change quantity - shipping costs error

Tags: ajax, magento2.3.4

I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002976/magento-2-reload-totals-cart-after-ajax-change-quantity) to reload cart with ajax after quantity changing -

```
$.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                /* Minicart reloading */
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                /* Totals summary reloading */
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
```

All work fine in Magento 2.3.6, Magento 2.4.0.
But in Magento 2.4.3 in total summary block shipping costs displayed incorrectly, namely equal to 0.
After reloading the page, everything is correct again.
Is it a M2.4.3 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have a solution.
In Magento 2.4.3 in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart the last line has be removed -

```
customerData.get('cart').subscribe(estimateTotalsShipping);
```

You need to restore this line, best rewrite this js file in your custom Theme.